# Change form submission URL based on button clicked

Tags: html, button

i want to use a `button` as a link to another page. i have looked around and read some solutions but none worked. i dont want to use `action` in my `form` tag because i might want to have couple of buttons as links in that `form` tag.

here is what i have tried last:(didnt work)

```
<button onclick="location.href='../ClientSide/Registration/registration.aspx'">register</button>
```

what am i doing wrong? or is there a better/other way?

i really would like to use only html if possible, if not then to use: javascript or asp.net( i dont know jquery or php)

Comment: So you want the form data to be posted to the URL that each button should point to?

Comment: yes, exacly what you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this *directly* using only HTML.

You have two options:

**Option 1** Post the data to a single script on the server that decides what to do based on which button is clicked.

```
<form action="/some-url.aspx" method="post">
  <button name="button_action" value="register">register</button>
  <button name="button_action" value="another">another</button>
</form>
```

Then your script at `/some-url.aspx` would decide what to do next based on the value of `button_action`.

**Option 2** Use JavaScript to change the `form`'s `action` attribute based on which button is clicked.

```
<form id="form-with-buttons" action="/some-url" method="post">
  <button id="register-button" data-url="/some-url.aspx">register</button>
  <button id="another-button" data-url="/another-url.aspx">another</button>
</form>

<script>
  $("#register-button, #another-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $("#form-with-buttons");

    form.prop("action", $(this).data("url"));
    form.submit();
  });
</script>
```

**Option 1** is more accessible but requires some messiness on the server side. **Option 2** is fairly clean but requires JavaScript and a little messiness to work. It really depends on where you want the extra logic and how you feel about the accessibility of your form.

Comment: he wants html without js and jquery

Comment: @ArsenIbragimov Hence **Option 1**. I gave him options and thought-out reasoning for each option.

Comment: Thank you very much! can you show me an example of the script that will be in "/some-url.aspx"?

Comment: @Cooper No, I do not know .NET. I'm a Ruby developer. :)

Comment: In Ruby, I would do this: `case params[:button_action] when 'register' do_something when 'another' do_something_else else raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound end`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `formaction="url"` tag on the `<input>` or `<button>`, as per: https://css-tricks.com/separate-form-submit-buttons-go-different-urls/

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery on you page and this code

```
$(function(){
   $("button").on("click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      location.href='../ClientSide/Registration/registration.aspx';
   })
});
```

e.preventDefault() makes form NOT SUBMITING

Comment: i really would like to use only html if possible

Comment: try onclick="return false; location.href='url'"

Comment: This does not post the form data to the server. It merely redirects the user to another page.

Answer (score -2):

A simple answer would be wrapping the button inside anchor

```
<a href='../ClientSide/Registration/registration.aspx'>
<button>Click Here</button>
</a>
```