# How to get HTML filed value without using form using Django and Python

Tags: python, django

I need one help . I need to get all html field value when user will click on different button in `views.py` file using Django and Python. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="boxwidthinnerdiv">
        Nuclear Mini Plant<br /><br />
        <select>
            <option>Reactor 1</option>
            <option>Reactor 2</option>
            <option>Reactor 3</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br /><br /><br />
        <a href="{% url 'start' %}"><button class="buttondiv" type="button">Start</button></a>
        <a href="{% url 'shut' %}"><button class="buttondiv">Shut Down</button></a>
        <a href="{% url 'suspend' %}"><button class="buttondiv">Suspend</button></a>
    </div>
```

Here when user will click on start button the select field value should get in `views.py` file which is given below.

```
def start(request):
    status = 1

def shut(request):
    status = 0

def suspend(request):
    status = 2
```

Here inside each action I need to get the select field selected value. Please help me.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a form? You can set the action url of the form dynamically based on a button click, if you want each submit to go to a different URL. Take a look at [this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985643/change-form-submission-url-based-on-button-clicked)

Comment: Well, this can't possibly work. Why don't you want to use a form?

Comment: @DanielRoseman : Can you please  share your idea by a post ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman : Here also I need to set status different based on button .

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple views or links for this. just add a name for button (name="type" for example) and value for each of them like this:

```
    <button name="type" value="start" class="buttondiv" type="button">Start</button>
    <button name="type" value="shut-down" class="buttondiv">Shut Down</button>
    <button name="type" value="suspend" class="buttondiv">Suspend</button>
```

then in your view check which one is pressed by getting the type value from post request.
example:

```
#views.py

def your_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('type') and request.POST.get('type') == "start":

            #do something when "Start" button pressed.

        elif request.POST.get('type') and request.POST.get('type') == "shut-down":

            #do something when "Shut Down" button pressed.

        elif request.POST.get('type') and request.POST.get('dl-type') == "suspend":

            #do something when "Suspend" button pressed.
    else:
        #do something when request is not post.
        #redirect or render a template for example.
```

all of your inputs like select will be available like a normal form.

You can print the post request to see what is available to use and get more understanding on how this works.